# Using an ArrayStack ADT with String complications(java)

Tags: java, generics, stack

I have an ArrayStack class that uses generic. In another class, I've used this ArrayStack to take in Strings. When I call the pop() method, the Stack returns the top object. The problem that I'm having is that when I try to do this:

```
//temp is a String
//tempStack is an ArrayStack<String>
temp = tempStack.pop();
```

I get the following error:

```
incompatible type
required: java.lang.String
found: java.lang.Object
```

How can I make my compiler know that the pop() returns a String at this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you instantiate `tempStack`? it should be something like this:

```
ArrayStack<String> tempStack = new ArrayStack<String>();
```

And the `pop()` method should be returning the generic type:

```
public T pop() {
    // implementation details
}
```

Comment: I wrote:

ArrayStack tempStack = new ArrayStack<String>();

That should be it. Thanks!

Comment: @user2997154 you're welcome! and be careful with the compiler's messages, this surely was reported as a warning